# How can I combine the contents of two cells in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I'd like to combine the contents of A1 "Hello," with the contents of B1 "It's Me" in the cell C1 so it will read "Hello, It's Me."

I know I can do it manually, but I have to repeat the process several times, so I was hoping there was a command for that. I am using excel for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following formula in C1: =A1&" "&B1

Placing a space between the quotes adds a space. You could include any punctuation you'd like, such as " - ", or simply write =A1&B1 to not include an extra space.

Comment: And if you want to make it permanent, do a special cut-n-paste of values only.